# How to seed data using EntityFramework Code first Migrations

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Hi I'm using the Beta 1 version of this nuGet package, the database is allready created and I need to know if there is a way to populate my tables through migrations. Thanxs

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The intro post shows how to seed data
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/11/29/code-first-migrations-beta-1-no-magic-walkthrough.aspx

> Seed data: 
>   Override the Seed method in this class to add seed data.
>   - The Seed method will be called after migrating to the latest version.
>   - You can use the DbContext.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method to avoid creating
>   duplicate seed data. E.g.

```
myContext.AddOrUpdate(c => c.FullName,
  new Customer { FullName = "Andrew Peters", CustomerNumber = 123 },
);
```

Comment: I was implementing the answer and I noticed that indeed I can write my seeds at the Configuration file, but everytime I use the Update-Database code, those seed are going to populate the DB, everytime! :( ... I try adding the seed on the migrations files instead, but I think it doesnt work that way. Can you help me with this, i just want those seeds populate my db once and not every time i go Update-Database, thanxs pal

Comment: You have access to the context at that point, you could easily do wrap a myContext.Tablename.Any() around the code block.

Comment: I actually find it's better to create a migration and use Sql("Insert blah...") instead of using AddOrUpdate.

Comment: This is a little out-of-date. That post for instance no longer exists. Good answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342459/best-way-to-incrementally-seed-data-in-entity-framework-4-3