# EF - Seed function not updating table

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

In asp.net webform application, trying to save user to AspNetUsers after UPDATE-DATABASE command. the following code doesnt do that. solution ?

```
        public Configuration()
        {
           AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        }

        protected override void Seed(MyApp.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            if (!context.Users.Any(u => u.Email == "some@mail"))
            {
                var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
                var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
                var user = new ApplicationUser { Email = "some@mail" };

                manager.Create(user, "password");
            }
        }
```

Comment: AFAIK, Seed is only called on a database creation, not for an upgrade. For this you need to enable [migration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448087/how-to-seed-data-using-entityframework-code-first-migrations).

Comment: @tschmit007 i have enabled migrations. and seed is called whenever u call UPDATE-DATABASE command on the Package Manager Console.

Comment: sorry, I was on the Seed of the database initializer. indeed, the Seed method of configuration is called. Have you considered the solution of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342459/best-way-to-incrementally-seed-data-in-entity-framework-4-3) ?

Comment: @tschmit007 10x, but i wanna know y my solution doesnt work

Comment: imho, that is because the only utpdate is the seed, so there is not real update, so seed is not called.

Comment: @tschmit007 `PM> update-database
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
No pending explicit migrations.
Applying automatic migration: 201408261438410_AutomaticMigration.
Running Seed method.`

Comment: well, try adding a context.SaveChanges(), but that is weird... what is the value of .Succeeded of IdentityResult returned by manager.Create ?

Comment: @tschmit007 context.SaveChanges() doesnt help and is not needed here

Comment: I know but it was my last idea with checking the .Succeeded valuer of the Create return in case of incorrect password: not long enough, not complicated enough....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add `ApplicationUser` you must have the property `Username` initialized.